# How to validate for un-connected edges to cell in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, mxgraph

Hi i'm facing problem with `validation` for **un-connected** `edges` to cells in `mxgraph`

**below image will show you my expectation:**

[image]

**Question:**  whenever i press validate button **un-connected** `edges` and `cells` must be **highlighted** with red color.

**For full view Codepen:**https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/pmELpL?editors=1100

**NOTE: PLEASE SEE CODEPEN LINK (https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/pmELpL?editors=1100) as BELOW CODE IS NOT WORKING**

**Full Code:**

```html
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006-2013, JGraph Ltd
  
  Dynamic toolbar example for mxGraph. This example demonstrates changing the
  state of the toolbar at runtime.
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Toolbar example for mxGraph</title>

 <!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
    
    function setGraphData(){
      var graphState ={"tagName":"mxGraphModel","children":[{"tagName":"root","children":[{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"0"}},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"1","parent":"0"}},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"2","value":"A","style":"","parent":"1","vertex":"1"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"x":"271.56251525878906","y":"82.44792175292969","width":"100","height":"40","as":"geometry"}}]},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"3","value":"B","style":"","parent":"1","vertex":"1"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"x":"678.2291717529297","y":"106.89236450195312","width":"100","height":"40","as":"geometry"}}]},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"4","value":"Bangalore","parent":"1","edge":"1"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"x":"0.0511","y":"-20","relative":"1","as":"geometry"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxPoint","attributes":{"x":"370.06251525878906","y":"109.95338610053051","as":"sourcePoint"}},{"tagName":"mxPoint","attributes":{"x":"676.7291717529297","y":"128.3869001543523","as":"targetPoint"}},{"tagName":"mxPoint","attributes":{"as":"offset"}}]}]},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"5","value":"C","style":"","parent":"1","vertex":"1"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"x":"1013.7847747802734","y":"83.55902862548828","width":"100","height":"40","as":"geometry"}}]},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"6","parent":"1","source":"3","target":"5","edge":"1"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"relative":"1","as":"geometry"}}]},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"7","value":"Not Connected","style":"","vertex":"1","parent":"1"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"x":"552","y":"267.640625","width":"100","height":"40","as":"geometry"}}]},{"tagName":"mxCell","attributes":{"id":"8","value":"Edge Not connected must highlight in red color","edge":"1","parent":"1","source":"5"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxGeometry","attributes":{"relative":"1","as":"geometry"},"children":[{"tagName":"mxPoint","attributes":{"x":"740","y":"260","as":"targetPoint"}}]}]}]}]};
      
      localStorage.setItem('graphState',JSON.stringify(graphState));
    }
    
     function html2json(html){
  if(html.nodeType==3){
   return {
    "tagName":"#text",
    "content":html.textContent
   }
  }
  var element = {
   "tagName":html.tagName
  };

  if(html.getAttributeNames().length>0){
   element.attributes = html.getAttributeNames().reduce(
    function(acc,at){acc[at]=html.getAttribute(at); return acc;},
    {}
   );
  }

  if(html.childNodes.length>0){
   element.children = Array.from(html.childNodes)
    .filter(
     function(el){
      return el.nodeType!=3
      ||el.textContent.trim().length>0
     })
    .map(function(el){return html2json(el);});
  }
  return element;
 }

 function json2html(json){
  var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, json.tagName);

  var addAttributes = function(jsonNode, node){
   if(jsonNode.attributes){
    Object.keys(jsonNode.attributes).map(
     function(name){
      node.setAttribute(name,jsonNode.attributes[name]);
     }
    );
   }
  }

  var addChildren = function(jsonNode,node){
   if(jsonNode.children){
    jsonNode.children.map(
     function(jsonChildNode){
      json2htmlNode(jsonChildNode,node);
     }
    );
   }
  }

  var json2htmlNode = function(jsonNode,parent){
   if(jsonNode.tagName=="#text"){
    return xmlDoc.createTextNode(jsonNode.content);
   }

   var node = xmlDoc.createElement(jsonNode.tagName);

   addAttributes(jsonNode,node);
   addChildren(jsonNode,node);

   parent.appendChild(node);
  }

  addAttributes(json,xmlDoc.firstElementChild);
  addChildren(json,xmlDoc.firstElementChild);

  return xmlDoc;
 }
  </script>

  <!-- Loads and initializes the library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

 <!-- Example code -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
  // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
  // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
  function main()
  {
      setGraphData();
   // Checks if browser is supported
   if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
   {
    // Displays an error message if the browser is
    // not supported.
    mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
   }
   else
   {
    // Defines an icon for creating new connections in the connection handler.
    // This will automatically disable the highlighting of the source vertex.
    mxConnectionHandler.prototype.connectImage = new mxImage('images/connector.gif', 16, 16);

    // Creates the div for the toolbar
    var tbContainer = document.createElement('div');
    tbContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
    tbContainer.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    tbContainer.style.padding = '2px';
    tbContainer.style.left = '0px';
    tbContainer.style.top = '0px';
    tbContainer.style.width = '24px';
    tbContainer.style.bottom = '0px';
    
    document.body.appendChild(tbContainer);
   
    // Creates new toolbar without event processing
    var toolbar = new mxToolbar(tbContainer);
    toolbar.enabled = false
    
    // Creates the div for the graph
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    container.style.left = '24px';
    container.style.top = '0px';
    container.style.right = '0px';
    container.style.bottom = '0px';
    container.style.background = 'url("editors/images/grid.gif")';

    document.body.appendChild(container);
    
    // Workaround for Internet Explorer ignoring certain styles
    if (mxClient.IS_QUIRKS)
    {
     document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
     new mxDivResizer(tbContainer);
     new mxDivResizer(container);
    }
 
    // Creates the model and the graph inside the container
    // using the fastest rendering available on the browser
    var model = new mxGraphModel();
    var graph = new mxGraph(container, model);

    // Enables new connections in the graph
    graph.setConnectable(true);
    graph.setMultigraph(false);

    // Stops editing on enter or escape keypress
    var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
    var rubberband = new mxRubberband(graph);
    
    var addVertex = function(icon, w, h, style)
    {
     var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
     vertex.setVertex(true);
    
     var img = addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
     img.enabled = true;
     
     graph.getSelectionModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function()
     {
      var tmp = graph.isSelectionEmpty();
      mxUtils.setOpacity(img, (tmp) ? 100 : 20);
      img.enabled = tmp;
     });
    };
    
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rectangle.gif', 100, 40, '');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rounded.gif', 100, 40, 'shape=rounded');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/ellipse.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=ellipse');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rhombus.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=rhombus');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/triangle.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=triangle');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/cylinder.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=cylinder');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/actor.gif', 30, 40, 'shape=actor');
        
        
           // read state on load 
    if(window.localStorage.graphState){ 
     var doc = json2html(JSON.parse(localStorage.graphState)); 
     var dec = new mxCodec(doc);
     dec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
    }

    // save state on change
    graph.getModel().addListener('change',function(){
      var codec = new mxCodec();  
      window.localStorage.graphState = JSON.stringify(html2json(codec.encode(
       graph.getModel()
      )));
    });
   }
  }

  function addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, prototype, image)
  {
   // Function that is executed when the image is dropped on
   // the graph. The cell argument points to the cell under
   // the mousepointer if there is one.
   var funct = function(graph, evt, cell, x, y)
   {
    graph.stopEditing(false);

    var vertex = graph.getModel().cloneCell(prototype);
    vertex.geometry.x = x;
    vertex.geometry.y = y;
     
    graph.addCell(vertex);
    graph.setSelectionCell(vertex);
   }
   
   // Creates the image which is used as the drag icon (preview)
   var img = toolbar.addMode(null, image, function(evt, cell)
   {
    var pt = this.graph.getPointForEvent(evt);
    funct(graph, evt, cell, pt.x, pt.y);
   });
   
   // Disables dragging if element is disabled. This is a workaround
   // for wrong event order in IE. Following is a dummy listener that
   // is invoked as the last listener in IE.
   mxEvent.addListener(img, 'mousedown', function(evt)
   {
    // do nothing
   });
   
   // This listener is always called first before any other listener
   // in all browsers.
   mxEvent.addListener(img, 'mousedown', function(evt)
   {
    if (img.enabled == false)
    {
     mxEvent.consume(evt);
    }
   });
      
   mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct);
   
   return img;
  }

 </script>
</head>

<!-- Calls the main function after the page has loaded. Container is dynamically created. -->
<body onload="main();" >
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: A quick glance around seems like you can query for the edge relations with getEdgeCount() , if there are none then update the style? See the mxCell docs here: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxCell-js.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: As per the comment, to validate the cells not connected to the parent cell or its branches, we can use a recursive function checking each connected edge starts from the parent cell and so on.

Due to the limit of characters, the original code snippet is removed.

```css
.not_connected * {
  color: red;
  font-color: red;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006-2013, JGraph Ltd
  
  Dynamic toolbar example for mxGraph. This example demonstrates changing the
  state of the toolbar at runtime.
-->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Toolbar example for mxGraph</title>

</head>

<!-- Calls the main function after the page has loaded. Container is dynamically created. -->

<body onload="main();">
  <button style="position:absolute; left:300px;padding:8px 40px;background:orangered;color:#fff;outline:none;border:none;z-index:100;" id="validate_btn">Validate</button>
</body>

</html>

<!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
  var graphStateJSON;
  var graph;

  function setGraphData() {
    var graphState = {
      "tagName": "mxGraphModel",
      "children": [{
        "tagName": "root",
        "children": [{
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "0"
          }
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "1",
            "parent": "0"
          }
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "A",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "460",
              "y": "80",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "C",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "460",
              "y": "190",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "4",
            "edge": "1",
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "2",
            "target": "3"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "relative": "1",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "5",
            "value": "B",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "280",
              "y": "190",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "6",
            "value": "D",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "663",
              "y": "193",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "7",
            "edge": "1",
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "2",
            "target": "5"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "relative": "1",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "8",
            "edge": "1",
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "2",
            "target": "6"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "relative": "1",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "9",
            "value": "E",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "660",
              "y": "260",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "10",
            "edge": "1",
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "6",
            "target": "9"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "relative": "1",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "11",
            "value": "F",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "280",
              "y": "260",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "12",
            "value": "G",
            "style": "",
            "vertex": "1",
            "parent": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "x": "459",
              "y": "257",
              "width": "100",
              "height": "40",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "tagName": "mxCell",
          "attributes": {
            "id": "13",
            "edge": "1",
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "11",
            "target": "12"
          },
          "children": [{
            "tagName": "mxGeometry",
            "attributes": {
              "relative": "1",
              "as": "geometry"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    };
    graphStateJSON = JSON.stringify(graphState);
  }

  function html2json(html) {
    if (html.nodeType == 3) {
      return {
        "tagName": "#text",
        "content": html.textContent
      }
    }
    var element = {
      "tagName": html.tagName
    };
    if (html.getAttributeNames().length > 0) {
      element.attributes = html.getAttributeNames().reduce(
        function(acc, at) {
          acc[at] = html.getAttribute(at);
          return acc;
        }, {}
      );
    }
    if (html.childNodes.length > 0) {
      element.children = Array.from(html.childNodes)
        .filter(
          function(el) {
            return el.nodeType != 3 ||
              el.textContent.trim().length > 0
          })
        .map(function(el) {
          return html2json(el);
        });
    }
    return element;
  }

  function json2html(json) {
    var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, json.tagName);
    var addAttributes = function(jsonNode, node) {
      if (jsonNode.attributes) {
        Object.keys(jsonNode.attributes).map(
          function(name) {
            node.setAttribute(name, jsonNode.attributes[name]);
          }
        );
      }
    }
    var addChildren = function(jsonNode, node) {
      if (jsonNode.children) {
        jsonNode.children.map(
          function(jsonChildNode) {
            json2htmlNode(jsonChildNode, node);
          }
        );
      }
    }
    var json2htmlNode = function(jsonNode, parent) {
      if (jsonNode.tagName == "#text") {
        return xmlDoc.createTextNode(jsonNode.content);
      }
      var node = xmlDoc.createElement(jsonNode.tagName);
      addAttributes(jsonNode, node);
      addChildren(jsonNode, node);
      parent.appendChild(node);
    }
    addAttributes(json, xmlDoc.firstElementChild);
    addChildren(json, xmlDoc.firstElementChild);
    return xmlDoc;
  }
</script>

<!-- Loads and initializes the library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

<!-- Example code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
  // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
  // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
  var graph;
  var graphView;
  var notConnectedCells = [];
  var parentCellId = "2";

  function main() {
    setGraphData();
    // Checks if browser is supported
    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
      // Displays an error message if the browser is
      // not supported.
      mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
    } else {
      // Defines an icon for creating new connections in the connection handler.
      // This will automatically disable the highlighting of the source vertex.
      mxConnectionHandler.prototype.connectImage = new mxImage('images/connector.gif', 16, 16);
      // Creates the div for the toolbar
      var tbContainer = document.createElement('div');
      tbContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
      tbContainer.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      tbContainer.style.padding = '2px';
      tbContainer.style.left = '0px';
      tbContainer.style.top = '0px';
      tbContainer.style.width = '24px';
      tbContainer.style.bottom = '0px';
      document.body.appendChild(tbContainer);
      // Creates new toolbar without event processing
      var toolbar = new mxToolbar(tbContainer);
      toolbar.enabled = false
      // Creates the div for the graph
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      container.style.position = 'absolute';
      container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      container.style.left = '24px';
      container.style.top = '0px';
      container.style.right = '0px';
      container.style.bottom = '0px';
      container.style.background = 'url("editors/images/grid.gif")';
      document.body.appendChild(container);
      // Workaround for Internet Explorer ignoring certain styles
      if (mxClient.IS_QUIRKS) {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        new mxDivResizer(tbContainer);
        new mxDivResizer(container);
      }
      // Creates the model and the graph inside the container
      // using the fastest rendering available on the browser
      var model = new mxGraphModel();
      graph = new mxGraph(container, model);
      // Enables new connections in the graph
      graph.setConnectable(true);
      graph.setMultigraph(false);
      // Stops editing on enter or escape keypress
      var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
      var rubberband = new mxRubberband(graph);
      var addVertex = function(icon, w, h, style) {
        var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
        vertex.setVertex(true);
        var img = addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
        img.enabled = true;
        graph.getSelectionModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function() {
          var tmp = graph.isSelectionEmpty();
          mxUtils.setOpacity(img, (tmp) ? 100 : 20);
          img.enabled = tmp;
        });
      };
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rectangle.gif', 100, 40, '');
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rounded.gif', 100, 40, 'shape=rounded');
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/ellipse.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=ellipse');
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rhombus.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=rhombus');
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/triangle.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=triangle');
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/cylinder.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=cylinder');
      addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/actor.gif', 30, 40, 'shape=actor');
      // read state on load 
      if (graphStateJSON) {
        var doc = json2html(JSON.parse(graphStateJSON));
        var dec = new mxCodec(doc);
        dec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
      }
      // save state on change
      graph.getModel().addListener('change', function() {
        var codec = new mxCodec();
        graphStateJSON = JSON.stringify(html2json(codec.encode(
          graph.getModel()
        )));
      });
    }
  }

  function addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, prototype, image) {
    // Function that is executed when the image is dropped on
    // the graph. The cell argument points to the cell under
    // the mousepointer if there is one.
    var funct = function(graph, evt, cell, x, y) {
      graph.stopEditing(false);
      var vertex = graph.getModel().cloneCell(prototype);
      vertex.geometry.x = x;
      vertex.geometry.y = y;
      graph.addCell(vertex);
      graph.setSelectionCell(vertex);
    }
    // Creates the image which is used as the drag icon (preview)
    var img = toolbar.addMode(null, image, function(evt, cell) {
      var pt = this.graph.getPointForEvent(evt);
      funct(graph, evt, cell, pt.x, pt.y);
    });
    // Disables dragging if element is disabled. This is a workaround
    // for wrong event order in IE. Following is a dummy listener that
    // is invoked as the last listener in IE.
    mxEvent.addListener(img, 'mousedown', function(evt) {
      // do nothing
    });
    // This listener is always called first before any other listener
    // in all browsers.
    mxEvent.addListener(img, 'mousedown', function(evt) {
      if (img.enabled == false) {
        mxEvent.consume(evt);
      }
    });
    mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct);
    return img;
  }

  function Validate(mxCell){
        let isConnected = true;
        // check each cell that each edge connected to
        for(let i=0;i<mxCell.getEdgeCount();i++){
            let edge = mxCell.getEdgeAt(i);

            if(edge.target === null) continue; // no target
            if(mxCell.getId() === edge.target.getId()) continue; // target is mxCell itself
            
            isConnected = edge.source !== null && edge.target !== null;
            if(isConnected){
                // remove source cell if found and so on
                let sourceIndex = notConnectedCells.findIndex(c=>c.id === edge.source.getId());
                if(sourceIndex !== -1) notConnectedCells.splice(sourceIndex,1);

                let targetIndex = notConnectedCells.findIndex(c=>c.id === edge.target.getId());
                if(targetIndex !== -1) notConnectedCells.splice(targetIndex,1);

                let edgeIndex = notConnectedCells.findIndex(c=>c.id === edge.getId());
                if(edgeIndex !== -1) notConnectedCells.splice(edgeIndex,1);

                // check next cell and its edges
                Validate(edge.target);
            }
        }
    }

    function ResetColor(state){
        state.shape.node.classList.remove("not_connected");
        if(state.text)
            state.text.node.classList.remove("not_connected");
    }

    function SetNotConnectedColor(state){
        for(let i=0;i<notConnectedCells.length;i++){
            let mxCell = notConnectedCells[i];
            let state = graphView.getState(mxCell);
            state.shape.node.classList.add("not_connected");
            if(state.text)
                state.text.node.classList.add("not_connected");
        }
    }

    document.querySelector("#validate_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        
        let cells = graph.getModel().cells;
        graphView = graph.getView();
        notConnectedCells.length = 0;

        // create an array of cells and reset the color
        for(let key in cells){
            if(!cells.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

            let mxCell = cells[key];
            if(!mxCell.isVertex() && !mxCell.isEdge()) continue;
            notConnectedCells.push(mxCell);
            let state = graphView.getState(mxCell);
            ResetColor(state);
        }
        
        // starts with the parent cell
        let parentCell = notConnectedCells.find(c=>c.id === parentCellId);
        Validate(parentCell);

        SetNotConnectedColor();
    })
</script>
```

---

First, set `graph` to a global variable. (`var graph = new mxGraph(container, model);`)

Then, get all `cells`(as an object) and `graphView` from `graph` and iterate all the cells checking if it's connected or not.

```
function Validate(){
    let cells = graph.getModel().cells;
    let graphView = graph.getView();

    for(let key in cells){
        if(!cells.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        let mxCell = cells[key];
        if(!mxCell.isVertex() && !mxCell.isEdge()) continue;

        let state = graphView.getState(mxCell);
        ResetColor(state);

        let notConnected = true;
        if(mxCell.isVertex()){
            for(let i=0;i<mxCell.getEdgeCount();i++){
                let edge = mxCell.getEdgeAt(i);
                // if any of an edge connected to both source and target, it's connected
                if(edge.source !== null && edge.target !== null){
                    notConnected = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else { // mxCell.isEdge()
            notConnected = mxCell.source === null || mxCell.target === null;
        }

        if(notConnected) SetNotConnectedColor(state);
    }
}

function ResetColor(state){
    state.shape.node.classList.remove("not_connected");
    if(state.text)
        state.text.node.classList.remove("not_connected");
}

function SetNotConnectedColor(state){
    state.shape.node.classList.add("not_connected");
    if(state.text)
        state.text.node.classList.add("not_connected");
}

document.querySelector("#validate_btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    Validate();
})
```

[And here's the localStorage version code if you want(codepen)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqyoxr?editors=1100)

Comment: That's really a great solution!!!,  but I want reference to be **A** for all validation,  if it is having parent as **A** then it is connected.  For the sake of understanding here **n**, **m** is not connected to **A** even though is validated as correct.  See codepen https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/MMogyw

Comment: How can we tell that **n**, **m** are having the same parent as **A** from the pen you provided?

Comment: For the sake of my problem consider **A** as a parent for every other node(I, e **m**, **n**.. )

Comment: **Your question**: if **m**, **n** is having closest or farthest parent as **A** then it is connected.

Comment: Please check the links again since they're all the same and considering update the question to the post for future readers.

Comment: hi @Hikarunomemory, please consider this example for `connectedness` and `unconnectedness`.  you are the only hope for me.

**1.connected** : https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/vqZQew
**3.connected** : https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/ZdymRv

**2.unconnected** : https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/WqOYMo

**4.unconnected** : https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/rEwQrv

Comment: hi  @Hikarunomemory, have seen my all codepen?? please reply  if you have not seen it.

Comment: I have already seen all of them and edited my post. If this is not what you want, please edit your question and give us some examples include the input(`graphState`) and expected output(in which case that some of the cells and edges would be highlighted)